# Does quasi-random number generator have a period?

Tags: probability, monte-carlo, quasi-monte-carlo

I read somewhere, maybe incorrectly, that the Niederreiter quasi-random generator in MKL is 32 bit, and hence as a period of 2^32.

This is pretty low, is this correct?

This made me wonder if quasi-random number generator have such thing as a period.
My understanding is that, the low discrepancy sequence should go on forever, without repeating itself.
Is this correct?

Or, say in another way, is the period of the Mersene-Twistter greater than the period of the Sobol/Niederreiter sequence?

Comment: why did this get migrated to CV? I would have thought stackoverflow is more appropriate. :P
BTW, all pseudo-random number generators are periodic, AFAIK.

Comment: @Memming Somebody at stackOF commented that my question will be more appropriate here. I don't know why. But my question received very little attention there, so I guess he was right.